# Is it possible to decode single level JSON into 2 separate models?

Tags: json, swift, struct, codable, decodable

I have a JSON response that contains information about a user.

```
{
  "userId": "123456789",
  "email": "\"some.email@some.domain.tld",
  "firstName": "\"foo\"",
  "lastName": "\"bar\"",
  "name": "\"foo bar",
  "bio": "\"boo baz\"",
  "age": "42"
}
```

I'd like to create 2 models, `User` and `Profile` from the same JSON, with a single request.

I'd then like `Profile` to be a property on the `User` struct.

At the moment, my standard struct looks like this -

```swift
struct User: Codable, Equatable {
    var userId: String
    var email: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var name: String?
    var bio: String?
    var age: Int?
}
```

I would prefer however to do something like this -

```
struct User: Codable, Equatable {
    var userId: String
    var email: String
    var profile: UserProfile // I'd like to wrap the profile info up in this field
}

struct UserProfile: Codable, Equatable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var name: String?
    var bio: String?
    var age: Int?
}
```

As `profile` does not exist on the response, I do not understand how I can decode the rest of the response into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should consider making all of the fields on your model [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

It is good practice not to change your data, but create an updated copy.

However, this should work -

```swift
let json = Data("""
 {
   "userId": "123456789",
   "email": "some.email@some.domain.tld",
   "firstName": "foo",
   "lastName": "bar",
   "name": "foo bar",
   "bio": "boo baz",
   "age": 42
 }
""".utf8)

struct User: Codable, Equatable {
    let userId: String
    let email: String
    let profile: UserProfile

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        userId = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .userId)
        email = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
        profile = try UserProfile(from: decoder)
    }

}

struct UserProfile: Codable, Equatable {
        let firstName: String
        let lastName: String
        let name: String?
        let bio: String?
        let age: Int?
}

var result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: json)
print(result.profile)
```